# Create program to generate CSV file using a custom query from Microsoft SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I want to create a program to export an CSV file from my database in Microsoft SQL, I built one using Python, but it's not working for me.

How this program will work, I will be setting in the Task Scheduler a daily task to run this exe, and then it will generate the CSV files and upload them to an SFTP server to integration some data with another platform.

```
import pyodbc
import csv

#SQL Details
server = ''
database = ''
username = ''
password = ''

#SQL Query

sql_query = ( I Cleared the query )

#Connection
connection_string = (
    f'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
    f'SERVER={server};'
    f'DATABASE={database};'
    f'UID={username};'
    f'PWD={password};'
)
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

# Create a cursor object to execute the query
cursor = connection.cursor()

try:
    # Execute the SQL query
    cursor.execute(sql_query)

    # Fetch all the rows returned by the query
    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    # Define the CSV file name to export results
    csv_file = 'results.csv'

    # Write the results to the CSV file
    with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(file)

        # Write the column headers first
        column_names = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
        csv_writer.writerow(column_names)

        # Write each row to the CSV file
        for row in rows:
            csv_writer.writerow(row)

    print(f"Data exported to {csv_file}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

finally:
    # Close the cursor and the connection
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

> Import "pyodbc" could not be resolved

Comment: Have you installed `pyodbc`? If yes, provide the command used to install it, and the command used to run your script.

Comment: Pip install pyodbc

Comment: "and the command used to run your script." My best guess is that the command used to run your script is run in a different environment than `pip install pyodbc`. If this is the case, figure out which python executable is being used to run your script, and install `pyodbc` using `<path_to_python_executable> -m pip install pyodbc`.

Comment: For the <path_to_python_executable>, do I only write the version of python? or file directory. 
I used python -m pip install pyodbc

Comment: and got this : - 


Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc in c:\users\yazee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.0.0-unsupported)

Comment: If you install `pyodbc` with `python -m pip install pyodbc`, then running your script via `python script.py` should have `pyodbc` in the PATH and and the import error won't occur. Note that you need to replace `script.py` with the filename of your script.

Comment: It worked now, I used to run the file in the terminal using the path and it worked, but the exported CSV is empty, there's no any column or and table as I mentioned in my query

Comment: Happy to hear the original error is resolved. You'll probably get better results if you address the data issue in a new question. Such a question should include sample data and the query used to fetch the data.